# Haskell type representing a subset of another type

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

**I think that when given parameter(s) of the specified type, a function should never fail.**

But take this seemingly innocuous code:

```
readInts :: String -> [Int]
readInts = map read . words
```

It has a type signature that is too general, in fact, it will fail for any string that is not composed by space separated integers, its type should then be:

```
readInts :: SpaceSeparatedIntegersString -> [Int]
```

When the program fails when you try to build a `SpaceSeparatedIntegersString` that does not respect the stated criteria.

- Is implementing a `SpaceSeparatedIntegersString` a sensible idea?
- If it is how can I implement such a type? (I ask just a general idea/tip/nudge in the right direction, not full code)
- Should I just accept that my function will fail when the `String` formatting is not correct (that is, my statement at the start of tis question is wrong)?
- Should I just use a guard clause in the function definition?

Comment: An alternative: `readInts :: String -> Maybe [Int]`. If you want to eschew all partial functions, you will need something similar with the `newtype` approach eventually (`fromString :: String -> Maybe SpaceSeparatedIntegersString`, for example). Which is better? It depends; it depends.

Comment: I'd just accept that functions can fail. In a perfect world, users would do everything right, all inputs would be validated, ..., but stuff happens. There's going to be a layer between your "perfect" functions and your "imperfect" functions anyway. If you're asking whether to make that layer as small as possible, then yes, that's a good idea with anything.

Comment: If that's is what you think is most important you probably want to use Coq instead of Haskell. In Coq all functions are total (and you have to prove it to the compiler). Note however that this requirement makes the language *non* Turing-complete (though it can still express quite a lot of functions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your goal is noble, but requires very precise types. Dependent types, such the ones available in Agda, Coq, Idris, and other languages can achieve what you propose. E.g. in Coq,

```
Definition SpaceSeparatedIntegersString: Type :=
   { s: string | spaceSeparatedIntegers s } .
Definition spaceSeparatedIntegers (s: String): Prop := ...
```

The catch is that, whoever wants to construct a `SpaceSeparatedIntegersString` value, must provide a formal proof of the relevant property. This is feasible, but requires some care, time and mathematical skills.

In Haskell, it is more common to move the type-guarantee to the output type. Instead of making the input type stronger, we can make the output type weaker:

```
readInts :: String -> Maybe [Int]
```

This is not as precise, but can be used without having to prove anything.

Alternatively, make `SpaceSeparatedIntegersString` be an opaque type by declaring it in a module without exporting its value constructors.

```
module Foo(SpaceSeparatedIntegersString(), ...)
data SpaceSeparatedIntegersString = S String        -- S is private
```

In this way, the users of the module will have to manipulate it only through functions exported by the module. With some care, one can craft a bunch of (exported) combinators which guarantee that values of type `SpaceSeparatedIntegersString` will never contain invalid strings.
For instance,

```
combine :: SpaceSeparatedIntegersString 
        -> SpaceSeparatedIntegersString
        -> SpaceSeparatedIntegersString 
combine (S x) (S y) = S (x ++ " " ++ y)
```

This is not entirely straightforward -- if you want to allow general string manipulation, you will probably end up in returning `Maybe ...` in some cases.

Comment: So you suggest writing my function like `readInts s | checkIfStringIsWellFormatted s = Nothing; readInts s = Maybe ( map read . words) ` ?

Comment: @Caridorc Roughly, yes. You can exploit `reads` or `readMaybe` (to be found in some module) to check whether the conversion suceeded, instead of using guards. (Also, on success it should be `Just (...)`).

Comment: Unless input strings are known statically, I would make `readInts` return either a proof that a string is ill-formed or a list of ints. Also, I would probably use a [view](http://lpaste.net/151196) instead of a proof-carrying sigma.

Comment: @user3237465 That would be indeed better. I proposed a sigma since the OP asked for a "subset of another type". By the way, what is `T` in your Agda snippet?

Comment: `T` makes a proposition from a boolean: `T true = ⊤; T false = ⊥`.

Answer (score 5):

You probably shouldn't implement `SpaceSeparatedIntegerString`.  If you did an abstract data type would be the simplest thing to do.  You should not accept that your function should fail, at least not in the "pattern match failure" sense.  You should make a function that returns something like `Maybe [Int]`.

The reason you shouldn't implement `SpaceSeparatedIntegerString` is that likely just pushes the problem elsewhere.  You probably are getting the `String`s from some input, so somewhere you need a function `String -> SpaceSeparatedIntegerString` and that could fail just as well.  At some point you need to go from less structured to more structured data unless your only values are completely statically specified.

The point is going from less structured data to more structured data (or less typed data to more typed data) is virtually always going to be a partial operation.  Indeed, parsing is the process of turning less structured data into more structured data.  What you *should* do, though, in line with your principle, is as much as practical *reify* the recovered structure into the type system.  So `isValidUri :: String -> Bool` is bad, as is `makeUri :: String -> Maybe String`, but `makeUri :: String -> Maybe Uri` where `Uri` is a type that can represent exactly the valid URIs is good.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a sensible idea in this case. The approach suggested in [Ian Henry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091571/haskell-type-representing-a-subset-of-another-type#comment57905281_35091571) using `Maybe` is one of several reasonable ones. The reason your idea is not sensible in this context is that the entire purpose of a function like `readInts` is to process input from the user, a file, an HTTP request, etc., which may *not* be valid. The type system can't help you if you ask the user how many cars they want to buy and they respond with a picture of a kitten. Derek Elkins really explains this better. chi's dependently typed approach is great for some other situations, once the input has been fully validated.

Comment: Do you mean the approach of `Maybe` or the approach of `newtype` ?

Comment: @Caridorc, using `Maybe`. If you need to deal with *streaming* input (for responsiveness, throughput, or large input size), you'll need a more refined sort of error handling, but `Maybe` will do for many purposes.